# AsyncStorage returns array to string react-native

Tags: android, arrays, objective-c, react-native, asyncstorage

I have an array that I stored on AsyncStorage as Json.stringfy. when I try to get the key it returns as a string. what I want is like this `[0:'apple', 1:'ball', 2:'car']`. following is the method I have tried

```
  useEffect(() => {
     AsyncStorage.getItem('@moduke').then(module => {
        const a = JSON.parse(module);
        console.log(a.length);
     });
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the String is surrounded by " ". and use " . when try to parse the above string by JSON.parse(), still return the string:`{"0:'apple', 1:'ball', 2:'car'}`, and `\"` is replaced by ". But use the JSON.parse() again, it will return the object i solved as below method

```
     useEffect(() => {
         AsyncStorage.getItem('@moduke').then(module => {
            const a = JSON.parse(module);
            const b = JSON.parse(a);
            console.log(b);
            console.log(b.length);
         });
      }, []);
```